# Why Priority queue preferred to implement using heap not by array although Heap itself implemented using array

Tags: heap, priority-queue

Why Priority queue preferred to implement using heap not by the array, although Heap itself implemented using an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary heap provides a partial ordering, which guarantees O(log n) insertion and O(log n) removal of the highest-priority item.

With a flat array, you have two choices:

1. Maintain an ordered array. Insertion becomes an O(n) operation, and removal of the highest-priority item is O(1).
2. Insert items in the order they're received. Insertion then becomes O(1), and removal of the highest-priority item is O(n).

Either of those two options makes the priority queue less efficient than if you implement a binary heap.